# How to remove default font family from ckeditor4 in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ckeditor4.x

We have implemented one page for CMS page,now we have to put only one custom font family and remove other font family.
So can you please give where we have to change for this functionality in ckeditor4 config file

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please do not use the font plugin. Then the Advanced Content Filter will automatically filter out spans with font-family style.and if needed You can either download a standard package which doesn't contain the font plugin, build your custom CKEditor package without that plugin or use the config.removePlugins in your config. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, i dot it but its display one undefined font family in drop-down.

Comment: I think you need do remove it from the font config as well

Comment: Go to ckeditor/plugins/font/plugin.js and find the following lines 

CKEDITOR.config.font_names="Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;Georgia/Georgia, serif;Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"; 

and try removing it from here the family you don't need